# how to draw a small image into canvas in android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I would like to ask on how to draw a small png file into the screen.

First I created an xml that shows the background picture.
now I wanted to place a small picture inside that xml using bitmap.

Is it possible? and how, sorry I am just new to android development.

Comment: Are you asking if you can embed an image as data inside the layout XML?

Comment: @DevinM I was thinking more of an image that can be moved, I am actually developing a side scroller game.

Comment: Have you gone through the Android tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

ImageView i=new ImageView(yourActivityClassName.this);

YourParentLayout.addView(i);

i.setImageBitmap(bm);